Excel VBA time-dependent crash
I have some Excel VBA code for automatically processing large data files on a daily basis. This has been in place for a few months now, and has until recently worked flawlessly. Last week, my software was updated to Office365 from the conventional Office suite, and now the same code has been crashing: at a certain point during execution, it will just stall for a while, and then unceremoniously close all open Excel instances. In trying to debug this, I found that I can usually avoid the problem using breakpoints (or stop statements), and take my time progressing beyond those breakpoints. So it appears that there is some transient state into which Excel puts itself during execution of the code where it is vulnerable to this crash. I can babysit the code through this, but that's getting tedious, and I would prefer a more stable solution. Any ideas on how to approach this? I'm copying the general structure of my code below:
Public Sub ExtendData()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook       'code is called from workbook to be updated
   i = 1: j = 0
   For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count  'find csv workbook containing new data among open books
      If (Left(Workbooks(i).Name, 9) = "data_" And Right(Workbooks(i).Name, 4) = ".csv") Then j = i
   Next i
   Workbooks(j).Activate
   Set csvsheet = ActiveSheet
   Set shdata = wb.Sheets("data")
   Set nextcell = shdata.[a2].End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   For Each cell In Range([a2], [a2].End(xlDown))   'simple manipulation of new data
      s = Left(Replace(cell, "T", " "), 19)
      cell.Value = DateValue(s) + TimeValue(s)
   Next cell
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   cols = csvsheet.[a1].End(xlToRight).Column
   Stop
   Range(csvsheet.[a2], csvsheet.[a1].End(xlDown).Offset(0, cols - 1)).Copy nextcell 'copy new data into master sheet
   csvsheet.Parent.Close False    'when crash occurs, it is here 
   wb.Activate
   'more manipulation here - if code progresses beyond this point, there is no crash
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Side notes: it'd be much better if you used arrays, qualified your Range calls with the parent worksheet/workbook, and avoided using Activate or ActiveSheet.

If this is a long running piece of code and you have auto save on, it will have issues trying to run while trying to save.  Ensure that auto save is off, and if necessary turn it on again as needed.

BigBen, why is it better to use arrays?

Copy and Manipulate Data

I decided to leave the source workbook intact i.e. to manipulate the column A values in the destination workbook.

Option Explicit

Sub ExtendData()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Extend Data"
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_NAME_PATTERN_LCASE As String = "data_*.csv"
    
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "data"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A2"
    Const DST_DATE_TIME_COLUMN As String = "A"
    Const DST_DATE_TIME_FORMAT As String = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    
    ' Reference the source objects.
    
    Dim swb As Workbook, swbName As String
    
    For Each swb In Workbooks
        If LCase(swb.Name) Like SRC_NAME_PATTERN_LCASE Then Exit For
    Next swb
    
    If swb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No workbook matching the pattern """ & SRC_NAME_PATTERN_LCASE _
            & """ found!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(1) ' the one and only
    
    Dim srg As Range, RowsCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        RowsCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If RowsCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Not enough rows in """ & sws.Name & "'!" _
                & .Address(0, 0) & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srg = .Resize(RowsCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the destination objects.
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim dcell As Range
    
    With dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        If dcell.Row < .Row Then Set dcell = .Cells
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Copy from source to destination and close source.
    
    srg.Copy Destination:=dcell
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' Convert the strings in the date/time column to date/time.
    
    ' Reference the date/time range.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dcell.EntireRow _
        .Columns(DST_DATE_TIME_COLUMN).Resize(RowsCount)
    
    Dim Data() As Variant, r As Long, DateTimeString As String
    
    ' Return the values from the range in an array.
    If RowsCount = 1 Then
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = drg.Value
    Else
        Data = drg.Value
    End If
    
    ' Convert the strings in the array to date/time.
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        DateTimeString = Left(Replace(Data(r, 1), "T", " "), 19)
        Data(r, 1) = DateValue(DateTimeString) + TimeValue(DateTimeString)
        ' Maybe just this could work instead of the previous two lines.
        'Data(r, 1) = Left(Replace(Data(r, 1), "T", " "), 19) ' without 'Left' ?
        ' Then you also might not need the 'drg.NumberFormat...' line!?
    Next r
    
    ' Write the values from the array to the range (and format).
    drg.Value = Data
    drg.NumberFormat = DST_DATE_TIME_FORMAT
    
    ' more manipulation here?

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Data extended.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub


Thanks for this. I learned a few new things, including the use of "like" to match a string pattern. Many of the changes you made relative to my code are a matter of preference, and I can see their merit. But do any of them make the code less likely to crash? There doesn't appear to be a fundamental difference, in terms of Excel operations, between my code and yours, besides the fact that you do the date/time manipulations in the master workbook rather than in the csv worksheet, and use an array to store results rather than immediately writing the data back to the worksheet.
